# Bootstrap: fixed space between columns?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make a responsive grid of pictures. I am using Bootstrap Grid but I want to always have same vertical space between my pictures.

```html
<div class="container-project-show">
  <div class="row">
    <% @pictures.each do |picture| %>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
        <%= cl_image_tag picture.path %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible to add the margin to the image in your grid:

```
.container-project-show img {margin: 10px auto;}
```

The alternative would be to add a shiv div around each image that controls spacing:

```css
.pad-10 {margin: 10px auto;}
```

```html
<div class="container-project-show">
  <div class="row">
    <% @pictures.each do |picture| %>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="pad-10">
        <%= cl_image_tag picture.path %>
          </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to **not** modify Bootstrap directly. Main reason is when you update bootstrap all of your changes will be erased. So instead of opening up bootstrap create (or modify) a CSS file. Instead of putting

```
<div class="container-project-show">
  <div class="row">
    <% @pictures.each do |picture| %>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
        <%= cl_image_tag picture.path %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

do:

```
<div class="container-project-show">
  <div class="row">
    <% @pictures.each do |picture| %>
      <div class="my-col-xs-12 my-col-sm-6 my-col-lg-4">
        <%= cl_image_tag picture.path %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then add the new classes in the new CSS file.